# Converting ordered dictionaries to dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dataset which might have n level of ordered dictionary of ordered dictionaries which might be again inside list of tuples or tuples or just lists,Now i need to convert all of them into normal dictionaries,Is there a easier method to do other than recursive search and conversion.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def ordered_to_regular_dict(d):
    if isinstance(d, OrderedDict):
        d = {k: ordered_to_regular_dict(v) for k, v in d.items()}
    return d
```

I got an answer from stack overflow which helps with  ordered dictionary of ordered dictionaries but not with the dictionaries inside list of tuple or ordered dictionary inside a list or a tuple.

Comment: I'm actually not sure, why you want to do this, given that an OrderedDict *is* also a dictionary. I would expect the overhead of the conversion to be bigger than the potential gain of marginally faster access afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just writing an if for every possibility (tuple, list, dict) like that:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def ordered_to_regular_dict(d):
    if isinstance(d, OrderedDict) or isinstance(d, dict):
        d = {k: ordered_to_regular_dict(v) for k, v in d.items()}
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        d = [ordered_to_regular_dict(v) for v in d.items()]
    elif isinstance(d, tuple):
        d = (ordered_to_regular_dict(v) for v in d.items())
    return d
```

Answer (score 0):

You should leverage Python's builtin [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) mechanism.

You can override copying behavior for `OrderedDict` via Python's [`copyreg`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copyreg.html#module-copyreg) module (also used by [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)). Then you can use Python's builtin [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) function to perform the conversion.

```py
import copy
import copyreg
from collections import OrderedDict

def convert_nested_ordered_dict(x):
    """
    Perform a deep copy of the given object, but convert
    all internal OrderedDicts to plain dicts along the way.

    Args:
        x: Any pickleable object

    Returns:
        A copy of the input, in which all OrderedDicts contained
        anywhere in the input (as iterable items or attributes, etc.)
        have been converted to plain dicts.
    """
    # Temporarily install a custom pickling function
    # (used by deepcopy) to convert OrderedDict to dict.
    orig_pickler = copyreg.dispatch_table.get(OrderedDict, None)
    copyreg.pickle(
        OrderedDict,
        lambda d: (dict, ([*d.items()],))
    )
    try:
        return copy.deepcopy(x)
    finally:
        # Restore the original OrderedDict pickling function (if any)
        del copyreg.dispatch_table[OrderedDict]
        if orig_pickler:
            copyreg.dispatch_table[OrderedDict] = orig_pickler
```

Merely by using Python's builtin copying infrastructure, this solution has several nice properties:

- Works for more than just JSON data.
- Works for arbitrary data hierarchies.
- Does not require you to implement special logic for each possible element type (e.g. `list`, `tuple`, etc.)
- `deepcopy()` will properly handle duplicate objects within the collection:

  ```py
  x = [1,2,3]
  d = {'a': x, 'b': x}
  assert d['a'] is d['b']

  d2 = copy.deepcopy(d)
  assert d2['a'] is d2['b']
  ```

  Since our solution is based on `deepcopy()` we'll have the same advantage.
- This solution also converts *attributes* that happen to be `OrderedDict`, not only collection elements:

  ```py
  class C:
      def __init__(self, a):
          self.a = a

      def __repr__(self):
          return f"C(a={self.a})"

  c = C(OrderedDict([(1, 'one'), (2, 'two')]))
  print("original: ", c)
  print("converted:", convert_nested_ordered_dict(c))
  ```

  ```
  original:  C(a=OrderedDict([(1, 'one'), (2, 'two')]))
  converted: C(a={1: 'one', 2: 'two'})
  ```